# GTL comparisons

Tags: marketing-cloud, gtl

I have the following GTL code wich workes fine:

```
{{#if Months!=""}}{{Months}}{{/if}}
```

However i want to do a double check. So i want to check if the field weeks is empty or greater than 1. I tried something like this but i got an error. Is this even possible with GTL?

```
{{#if Months>"1" or Months!=""}}{{Months}}&nbsp;maanden{{/if}}
```

Thanks for helping.